# What is the difference between these two linq queries? The first one will not work. The second will. Why?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have my code using the following linq:

```
var consulta = from grupo in Contexto.Set<GRUPOCONTRATO>()
               join detalhe in Contexto.Set<GRUPOCONTRATODETALHE>()
               on grupo.CDGRUPOCONTRATO equals detalhe.CDGRUPOCONTRATO
               where grupo.NOGRUPOCONTRATO.Contains("FACIL")
               && detalhe.NRCONTRATO == carteira.NumeroDoContrato
               select detalhe;
PlanoFacil = consulta.Any();
```

The code above wont work and throws an exception like this:
Object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Dominio.PERICIA]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet`1[Dominio.PERICIA]'.

Please note that it points to a problem with another entity (PERICIA) which has nothing to do with the query and has no relationship with the two entities in the query...

But if I split the query like this it works:

```
var consulta =  from grupo in Contexto.Set<GRUPOCONTRATO>()
                join detalhe in Contexto.Set<GRUPOCONTRATODETALHE>()
                on grupo.CDGRUPOCONTRATO equals detalhe.CDGRUPOCONTRATO
                where grupo.NOGRUPOCONTRATO.Contains("FACIL")
                //&& detalhe.NRCONTRATO == carteira.NumeroDoContrato
                select detalhe;

PlanoFacil = consulta.Any(detalhe => detalhe.NRCONTRATO == carteira.NumeroDoContrato);
```

Why?

Comment: I tried similar situation in my application but without any error. Could you post your model? Maybe this would help.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot post the model here due to my customer's internal policies... What I can say is that it is a DevArt Entity Developer model, not the standard edmx model... I checked the model to see it there are any relationships between the entities in the query and the entity PERICIA, but there aren't...

Comment: Can you post a simplified example model that mimics the core parts of what's in play here, without the actual names of the real model, so we can have a better understanding of what's going on?